# Divergence theorem in physics | divergence multiplied by a scalar

Tags: divergence-operator

I know that in physics the divergence of a vector over a volume is equal to the dot product of the vector by the normal to the surface, over the surface, ie:

$$\int_{\Omega} \nabla \cdotp \vec{u}\ d\Omega = \int_{\Gamma} u\ \cdotp n\ d\Gamma$$
In my case my vector is the gradient of a scalar function $f(\alpha)$ depending of the scalar $\alpha$ and i'm in the following case:
$$\int_{\Omega} \alpha\nabla \cdotp \nabla f(\alpha)\ d\Omega$$
I've a scalar inside on my integrale, infront of my divergence. Can i write:
$$\int_{\Omega} \alpha\nabla \cdotp \nabla f(\alpha)\ d\Omega = \int_{\Gamma} \alpha \nabla f(\alpha)\cdotp n\ d\Omega $$
or is this false ? Note that $\alpha$ is variable through $\Omega$.
Thanks.

Comment: If $\alpha$ is a scalar, then how is $\nabla f(\alpha)$ defined? Do you mean $f$ is a scalar function of the vector $\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is in $\Omega$?

Comment: $\alpha$ is a scalar, varying through my pysicial space $\Omega$. $f$ is a scalar function.  $\nabla f(\alpha)$ is the vector ${\frac{\partial f(\alpha)}{\partial x}\vec{e_x}\ \ \frac{\partial f(\alpha)}{\partial y}\vec{e_y}\ \  \frac{\partial f(\alpha)}{\partial z}\vec{e_z}}$

Comment: If your physical space $\Omega$ is comprised of scalars, then is $\Omega$ just a subset of the real number line $\Bbb R$? I.e. it is one-dimensional? Or do you mean $\alpha$ is *itself* is a scalar function of the vector in $\Omega$, as in $\alpha(x,y,z)$?

Comment: Yes, $\alpha$ is a scalar function of the vector in Ω, as in α(x,y,z)

Comment: That's something you should mention in your question. And then the answer is that your theorem does not imply your desired equality, since the theorem does not have any scalar function in front of the divergence.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry for the missing details. Could you anwser "officialy" so that i close the question ?